# Should comments from SOCE5000 be considered in aggregate?

Tags: discussion, comment-evaluator-5000

On their own I'd be ok with the below comments, but in aggregate that could change.

[image: Four comments with the same test but different]

In a different case could they need to be considered together?

Comment: I have no access to this Comment Evaluator, but I'm not intending to pull any punches here.  Think of it like this - do you see all of these comments at once?  Do you believe that the nature of them is truly disrespectful in their own context?  If you don't know, is there some way that you can skip this?

Comment: @Makoto I think just refreshing would skip. I'm goign to clarify my intent with this post.

Comment: This is yet another situation where I would like to evaluate them into a separate category: **annoying** (neither fine nor unfriendly per se)

Comment: This sort of behaviour can be classed as harassment (at the very least disrespectful) if they are all pinging the same user but based on the variations of the blacking out that doesn't seem to be the case except for the first and last one.

Comment: @Script47 they were all different

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you should consider them in aggregate. Or rather, you should consider them in *context*, which... amounts to the same thing in this specific instance.

Of course, there are bits of context that aren't available - such as the identity of the author, and whether said author is a 3-year-old child in the back of a car on a long trip. If you choose to rate those comments, you'll just have to do so without those pieces of information.

As always, vote your conscience.